# How to count the number of bytes in a file, grouping the same bytes?

Tags: linux, command-line, files, binary, byte

Example: I have the file "mybinaryfile", and the contents in hex are:

```
A0 01 00 FF 77 01 77 01 A0
```

I need to know how many A0 bytes there are in this file, how many 01, and so on. The result could be:

```
A0: 2
01: 3
00: 1
FF: 1
77: 2
```

Is there some way to make this count directly in shell or do I need to write a program in whatever language to do this specific task?

Comment: Looking at answers, this seems to be a worthy codegolf ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This uses [od](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) to show one hex value per line, then sorts and counts:

```
od -t x1 -w1 -v -An mybinaryfile | sort | uniq -c
```

(`-w1` is an extension, it’s not mandated by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html).)

Comment: Alternatives to od are: `xxd -c1 -p file`  and/or `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X \n"' file`.

Answer (score 5):

Using Perl to unpack the slurped file to a byte array and then use a hash to count unique bytes:

```
printf '\xA0\x01\x00\xFF\x77\x01\x77\x01\xA0' | 
  perl -0777 -nE '
    @bytes = unpack("C*",$_) 
    }{ 
    $counts{$_}++ for @bytes; 
    for $k (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %counts) {
      printf "%02X: %d\n", $k, $counts{$k}
    }
 '
00: 1
01: 3
77: 2
A0: 2
FF: 1
```

If a sufficiently recent version of `List::MoreUtils` is available, you may be able to simplify  the counting by using its `frequency` function.

Answer (score 1):

Quick Python solution:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, itertools, collections
print(
    *itertools.starmap(
        "{:02X}: {:d}".format,
        collections.Counter(sys.stdin.detach().read()).items()),
    sep="\n")
```

One-liner:

```sh
python3 -c 'import sys, itertools, collections; print(*itertools.starmap("{:02X}: {:d}".format, collections.Counter(sys.stdin.detach().read()).items()), sep="\n")' \
    < input.bin
```

---

#### Options and caveats

- If you want to the output sorted by frequency in descending order, replace `.items()` with [`.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common). Alternatively or for other sorting schemes, use the built-in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function or post-process the output with the [`sort(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) program.
- In its current state, the programs slurps the entire standard-input data into a byte buffer which is fine for relatively small files. For larger files, the program needs to be rewritten to [read files in chunks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read).

Answer (score 1):

- `< my_binary_file xxd -p | fold -w 2 | sort | uniq -c`

  ```
     1 00
     3 01
     2 77
     2 a0
     1 ff
  ```
- `< my_binary_file xxd -p | fold -w 2 | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2": "$1}'`

  ```
  00: 1
  01: 3
  77: 2
  a0: 2
  ff: 1
  ```

## Explanation

- `< my_binary_file` passes the contents of `my_binary_file` to the standard input of the `xxd` command.
- `xxd -p` converts the data read from its standard input in a hexadecimal dump, and the modifier `-p` (plain) tells the program to output only the digits without offsets nor textual representation.
- `fold -w 2` inserts a newline character every two characters (`-w 2`), converting the input stream to a newline-separated byte list.
- `sort`, as the name suggests, sorts the lines grouping the byte values.
- `uniq -c` counts the occurrences of each value in the input data.
- Optionally, a bit of `awk` magic converts the output format to the requested in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is very large you can count and sort as you go

```
od -t x1 -w1 -v -An binaryfile |
    awk '{h[$1]++} END {for (v in h) {printf "%d\t%s\n", h[v], v} }' |
    sort -k2
```

If you need a POSIX solution

```
od -t x1 -v -An binaryfile |
    tr ' ' '\n' |
    awk '$1 > "" { h[$1]++ } END { for (v in h) {printf "%d\t%s\n", h[v], v} }' |
    sort -k2
```